How can i import a 1 terabyte bacpac to an Azure SQL Server?
I have a 1 terabyte bacpac file. I have this file residing in an Azure Storage account.
I have tried using SSMS, SQLPackage, Azure Portal and Powershell and they all fail in importing.
Is there a way i can import this bacpac file, has anyone come across this before?
Update: Import Screen

Updated:
errors:
This is through Azure portal
The ImportExport operation with Request Id [] failed due to 'The operation was interrupted and cannot continue. Please drop the database, re-create it, and try again.
The operation was not cancle or interrupted.
These are through sqlpackage
*** An unexpected failure occurred: Data plan execution failed with message One or more errors occurred.
(One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The underlying compression routine could not reserve sufficient memory.))).
One or more errors occurred.
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown (mscorlib)

"they all fail in importing." - with what error? For all we know they fail because you misspelled the filename, not because it's too big.

No file name is not mispelled .. give out of memory exception . The error would say file not found even before it runs thats self explanatory\

[Edit] your question to tell us what the error is. It's not "self explanatory" to us that you're not getting a "file not found" error, because there's no errors in your question.

the question has been updated

What happens if you bump-up your Azure SQL's performance tier to, say, 1600 DTUs or higher, while you do the import?

I have and get this error :     The ImportExport operation with Request Id '' failed due to 'The host process exceeded its memory allowance. Retries will not be successful.

what im asking has anyone encountered this and if so how did the fix it ?

@Melissa Microsoft's docs say that when handling .bacpac files over 4GB in size you should use SqlPackage.exe instead of the Azure Portal.

@Melissa Another option is to eschew the official tooling and instead extract the .bcp files out from the .bacpac file and manually import them using bcp.exe - there is little documentation about this, so you'll have to spend some time doing your own reverse-engineering of the BCP tooling.

I have tried sqlpackage , but it seems to get stuck when Processing Tables. It has been processing one table for about 6hrs ?

Following the guide you have to:

Go into the SQL Server and import the backup from there. Now the backup is on the Server



Now create a database and go into Additional Settings > Use existing data > Backup, and select your backup.



When i click on Import Database , the screen is not what you have above. I have added the image above in the question as Update : Import Screen
